# DVI-D to Thunderbolt - new Mac Mini

Tags: mac, mac-mini, thunderbolt, dvi

I am buying a new Mac Mini that has one of these new Thunderbolt ports to connect to monitors. I know that this Thunderbolt port is equivalent to mini Display Port. My monitor is a Samsung 2232BW+ that has one of this DVI-D Single Link connectors. See next picture:

[image]

but all adapters I find are like this:

[image]

all informations I find, say that my monitor is DVI-D Single Link but the adapter is said to be DVI DUAL link.

Looking at both connectors, I see that in theory a DVI-D cable can connect to the DVI dual link, but I want to be sure.

Will it work if I buy one of these connectors in the second picture to use with my DVI-D monitor? Or what other cable do you recommend to connect a new mac mini with a thunderbolt port to a DVI-D monitor?

thanks.

Comment: The mDP>DVI adapter you have is a single-link adapter, so it will only use the single-link pins anyway, even if you were to hook up a dual-link cable and monitor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that will work just fine.  Notice that the female DVI connector has more slots than the male connector has pins.  Those slots are for the extra pins needed by a dual link cable.  They're not needed for a single link DVI connection, so they'll just sit unused.

Comment: thanks, but just one theoretical question. What exactly are the role of these pins. I mean, suppose my mac mini sends signal using the adapter exactly to these missing pins. In this case my monitor will not work... right? what is the certainty I have this will really work.

Comment: It's fine.  Those extra pins double the available bandwidth by doubling the number of pins (hence the term "dual-link DVI").  Your 22" display isn't anywhere near high enough resolution to need that bandwidth.  Also, DVI is two way communication, so the Mac Mini will know full well it's not dual-link and won't try to use it.

Comment: The extra pins your cable doesn't have are the "auxiliary" pins. They are only used in a situation with Dual-Link DVI: the primary signalling pins are always used, and you have them.

Comment: By the way, the overwhelming majority of those adapters will be used for single-link DVI connections set up exactly as you describe.  I'm actually using one to type this.  You don't need dual-link DVI until you get up to 27" displays, which are still quite rare.

Comment: As a side-note, the dual-link pin sockets in those adapters are actually not even connected. To use a Dual-Link monitor with a displayport/thunderbolt output, you need the ($100) [Displayport->DVI-DL converter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A).

Comment: The reason for the extra sockets on the adapter are to let you use a dual-link cable (which can *carry* single link).